# How do I put specific files/components into specific Inno Setup .bin files?

Tags: directory, inno-setup

Lets say I have 3 folders with files in them, A B and C. I want the user to be able to download either A B or C as separate `.bin` files, and install it with the same Inno Setup installer.

In the *"what components do you want installed"* screen, the ones that aren't in the same directory as the installer .exe are grayed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inno Setup cannot do this for you.

You would have to code it yourself.

ZIP the components to separate ZIP files. And have Inno Setup unzip them.